# Error uploading audio blob as wav to local server folder

Tags: javascript, php, blob, wav

i'm using the https://github.com/addpipe/simple-web-audio-recorder-demo to try to record a audio in browser and upload the audio blob to a wav on local server. But this was the start of a nightmare.

i've searched through the internet for at least 2 weeks from now but didn't find a solution to my issue.

I've tried using ajax, using pure javascript, logging everything trying to find how to get maybe the wav from the browser and maybe this would give me a direction.

This is the code:

javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Server returned: ", e.target.responseText);
        }
    };
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("audio_data", blob, filename);

    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(fd);
```

php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
 $filename = $_FILES['audio_data']['name'];

$location = "upload" .$filename;


$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'], $location);
    echo $location;
if($moved){
    echo "Uploaded";
}else{
    echo "Not Uploaded";
}
```

This is the information of the blob:(i got it by commenting the move_uploaded_file)

```
Server returned:  Array
(
    [audio_data] => Array
        (
            [name] => 2019-05-20T20:07:25.895Z
            [type] => audio/wav
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php6DF9.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 24620
        )

)
```

Also there's no file in the tmp_name location, is this normal?

I'm getting now this error.

```
Server returned:  PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(upload2019-05-20T19:43:29.314Z): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\Leffa\web\rectest\upload.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php95CF.tmp' to 'upload2019-05-20T19:43:29.314Z' in D:\Leffa\web\rectest\upload.php on line 13
```

I apreciate all help that ends my suffering ;-;

Comment: You're missing the `/` between upload and the file name here: `$location = "upload" .$filename;`, so it should be `$location = "upload/" . $filename`. Windows also seems to reserve colons (`:`) in filenames, so you might run into trouble there as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file

Comment: I see you've tried debugging from the server side. Have you tried monitoring what is being sent from the client side using your browser's tools? Your JS example is incomplete by the way...where does `blob` come from in your code? But...check the folder name as mentioned above, first. It looks like a file probably is being uploaded, if you've got a temp location listed for it. Client side verification would be useful after that if you still can't sort it

Comment: P.s. I'd expect there probably to be no file in the temp location most of the time, it won't persist for very long - probably not even beyond the end of the request in which it was uploaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817360/where-does-php-save-temporary-files-during-uploading and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301814/reusing-the-temporary-file-created-by-a-file-upload-in-a-php-form

Comment: thanks for all the responses, all try to remove the colons from the filename and see if it will work out
also i'm naming the file by date().toISOString, i need to remove the colons from this somehow...

Comment: IT WORKED!
replacing the : with . or something that isn't reserved does the trick to upload it,